# How to pass s same object's property to a function in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an interface for employee as shown below

```
export interface IEmployee {
    name: string;
    id: number;
    annualSalary: number;
    calculateMonthlySalary(annualSalary: number): number;
}
```

component that implements the above interface

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { IEmployee } from './../employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main',
  templateUrl: './main.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main.component.css']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit, IEmployee {

  employees: IEmployee[];

  constructor() {
    this.employees = [
      {name: 'john', id: 1, annualSalary: 90000, calculateMonthlySalary: this.calculateMonthlySalary(annualSalary) }
    ];
  }

  calculateMonthlySalary(annualSalary: number): any {
    return annualSalary / 12;
  }

}
```

Here, i'm trying to compute the monthly salary by using the interface `calculateMonthlySalary` method and trying to display in view using `*ngFor` but getting below error

`ERROR ReferenceError: annualSalary is not defined`

Please Correct me where i'm doing wrong

Comment: Do you want to referrence the object property ? then you'll need to use getters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vyk387?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
this.employees = [
  {name: 'john', id: 1, annualSalary: 90000, calculateMonthlySalary: this.calculateMonthlySalary(90000) }
];
```

When you are adding objects of Type IEmployee to the array, the object itself doesn't understand `annualSalary`, so you have to add it in the `calculateMonthlySalary()` function

To do it dynamically,you can create a Employee Class:

**[Working Demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p9fwgj?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

```
export class Employee {
  name: string;
  id: number;
  annualSalary: number;
  monthlySalary:number
  constructor(name: string, id: number, annualSalary: number) {
    this.name = name,
    this.id = id,
    this.annualSalary = annualSalary,
    this.monthlySalary = this.calculateMonthlySalary(annualSalary)

 }

 calculateMonthlySalary(annualSalary: number): any {
    return annualSalary / 12;
 }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
employees: Employee[];

  constructor() {
    this.employees = [
      new Employee('John',1,90000)
    ];
  }
```

Template:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>MonthlySalary</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of employees">
        <td>{{item.id}}</td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td>{{item.monthlySalary}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `annualSalary` is a key and not a value in this object.

Try this:

```
const salary = 9000;
this.employees = [
      {name: 'john', id: 1, annualSalary: salary, calculateMonthlySalary: this.calculateMonthlySalary(salary) }
    ];
```